# Replacing Text without losing inner tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Let suppose I have a string:

```
var firstString = "<h3>askhaks</h3><h3>1212</h3><h1 style='color:red;
text-decoration:underline;'><a href=''><span id='123'><i class='fa fa-inr'></i> 
</span> Hello! Admin</span></a></h1><p>This is the content of page 'String 
Replace in Javascript'</p><h1>First</h1><span><h1>Hello! Admin</h1>Thank You for 
visiting this page</span><h1>Third</h1>";
```

I want to change text of first `<h1>` tag without losing all other inner tags i.e. `<a href=''><span id='123'><i class='fa fa-inr'></i> </span>`

Just want to replace Hello! Admin with another text. I am able to replace text of first `<h1>` tag with the below code without losing the inline styling added to `<h1>` but I am loosing the inner tags.

```
var innerText = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML;
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Er, by `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')` it seems like you have an *element* in a document, not just a string? Which is it?

Comment: I am trying to create code just be inserting it in the document. Actually I want to achieve this in ckeditor.

Comment: if you want to manipulate the DOM, the parts you want to manipulate must be addressable ("selectable"). Plain old text is not selectable. Enclose your text in a tag such as `<span id="h1-test">Hello! Admin</span`, then you can retrieve it and modify it to your heart's content.

Comment: @torazaburo Well, plain text *is* selectable using DOM traversal and checking to see if a node is a text node, but yeah, it's probably not something one should do if one can avoid it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are indeed right, and if you wrote an answer using that technique it'd be far and above the best one yet. Actually, though, the same question has been answered about 100 times already, so if you have more time to spend on this question, why not find the best dup and mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the text *before* inserting it into the document, you can use `DOMParser` on the input HTML string, get its trimmed `textContent`, and then `replace` the substring in the input with your desired string, thus preserving all HTML tags:

```js
var firstString = "<h3>askhaks</h3><h3>1212</h3><h1 style='color:red;text-decoration:underline;'><a href=''><span id='123'><i class='fa fa-inr'></i></span> Hello! Admin</span></a></h1><p>This is the content of page 'String Replace in Javascript'</p><h1>First</h1><span><h1>Second</h1>Thank You for visiting this page</span><h1>Third</h1>";
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(firstString, 'text/html');
const h1Text = doc.querySelector('h1').textContent.trim();
console.log(firstString.replace(h1Text, 'foo bar new string'));
```

Comment: Yes, your code will work fine but what if the same text is available in any other line also.

Comment: If you want to replace that text wherever it appears as well, you can use a global regex replace.

Comment: You are not getting my point, if the same text is available in the firstString variable, then it will also get replaced. But I don't want it to get replaced.

Comment: Do you mean you want the `firstString` variable to remain as is? Then the code works as desired - strings are immutable. `.replace` *returns* a new string, it doesn't change the existing string.

Comment: This won't work if the text content is spread around in between different tags. The `.textContent` will be all the concatenated pieces of text, and the `replace` won't be able to find them.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please check the question once again, I have edited it. Now I have Hello Admin! text in two place but I don't want the second occurence of Hello Admin! to get replaced

Comment: @AkshitAhuja Then just use the code in the answer - it works as intended, only the first occurrence is replaced when you pass a string to `.replace`. https://jsfiddle.net/ep27nx0u/

Comment: Yes, its working fine. Thanks for the help @CertainPerformance

Comment: @AkshitAhuja When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hey..check your jsfiddle it's replacing all occurences of the text. Actually there is a space before the first Hello! Admin text that's why you seem that it is not replacing all other occurences

Comment: @AkshitAhuja The fiddle output is `<h3>askhaks</h3><h3>1212</h3><h1 style='color:red;text-decoration:underline;'><a href=''><span id='123'><i class='fa fa-inr'></i></span> foo bar new string</span></a></h1><p>This is the content of page 'String Replace in Javascript'</p><h1>First</h1><span><h1>Hello! Admin</h1>Thank You for visiting this page</span><h1>Third</h1>` The second instance of "Hello! Admin" is still there, as desired. `.replace` will only replace all occurrences if you pass a *regular expression*. If you pass a string, it will only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML = "Hello!";

Answer (score 0):

If it’s not in the DOM and it’s a string you can use a regex in a replace like:

```
str.replace(“(<h1>)(.+)(<\/h1>)”, “$1YOUR_NEW_TEXT$2”);
```